# how to update client status in specific node on button click in firebase database realtime react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The documentation describes how to change superficially without subtle nuances.need to change in the zero, first, second or third node to choose from

Here is a picture of the database.

[image: my example database]

Here is the request i am writing.

[image: try to write request to database]

Comment: what is your issue exactly ?

Comment: instead of photos, try putting the entire code in your question. Or better yet, put your entire project in a codesandbox and link it here. right now, its impossible to help you because the question does not make sense

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode